# Rally SDK Dropdown

Tags: rally

I am trying to write some js using Rally sdk to get a list of team members associated with a project. My Dropdown box will contain my current project as well a list of its child projects. Once selected, it will give a list of team members for the selected project.

So far, I tried doing it in two ways:

1. A rather simple approach without all child projects, in this I just get the first level child projects of my current project (not recursively getting all child projects).
2. Recursively getting all child projects of current project.

Till now, I am just able to complete (1) and just get all the first level child projects in the dropdown (haven't proceeded further to get the team members yet).However, I am having some problems in the approach (2).

Using recursion, I am able to get all the projects in an array and pushing it correctly, but the list doesn't show up in the dropdown box. Note that I am testing my code by copy-pasting it in Rally as a custom html.I also do not get any error to understand what may be possibly wrong.

This is my approach 1:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var projects_array = new Array();
    var child_project = new Array();
    function onLoad() {
        //Add app code here


        loadProjectDropdown();
    }

    function loadProjectDropdown()
    {

          var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource("__WORKSPACE_OID__","__PROJECT_OID__","__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__","__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__");


        var queryArray = new Array();
        queryArray.push({
            key:"projects",
            type:"project",
            fetch: "Children,Name",
            query: rally.sdk.util.Query('ObjectID = "' + '__PROJECT_OID__' + '"')   

            });

        rallyDataSource.findAll(queryArray,processQueryArray);

    }

    function processQueryArray(results){

        var data = new Array();

        var project = results.projects;

        /*
         * 
         * This is just a test from Rohan
         */
        var all_projects = new Array();
        data.push({label: project[0].Name, value: project[0].Name});

        if(project[0].Children != null)
        {
            for(var i=0;i<project[0].Children.length;i++)
            {
                //document.write("Number "+i+" "+project[0].Children[i].Name);
                data.push({label: project[0].Children[i].Name, value: project[0].Children[i].Name});
            }
        }


        //pass the first parent project to a function that recursively gets all child projects.

        //all_projects = get_child_recursively(project[0]); 


        //document.write(JSON.stringify(all_projects));

        /*for(var i=0;i<all_projects.length;i++)
        {
            data.push({label: all_projects[i].Name, value: all_projects[i].Name});
            //document.write(JSON.stringify(all_projects[i]));
            //data.push({label: all_projects[i].Name, value: all_projects[i].Name});
        }*/

        projectDropDown = new rally.sdk.ui.basic.Dropdown({label: "Select Project", items: data, width: 250});
        projectDropDown.display("projectDropDown",projectDropDownChanged);
    }

    //Recursive algorithm to get all child projects of a parent project
    //Nothing wrong with this code, I have commented this function for appraoch 1
    function get_child_recursively(parent_project)
    { 

            //check if this project is in array
            projects_array.push(parent_project);

            if(parent_project.Children.length>0)
            {
                for(var i=0;i<parent_project.Children.length;i++)
                {
                    if(child_project.indexOf(parent_project.Children[i])<=-1)
                        child_project.push(parent_project.Children[i]);
                }
                for(var i=0;i<child_project.length;i++)
                {   var temp = child_project[i];
                    child_project.splice(i,1);
                    get_child_recursively(temp);
                }
            }
            else{
                return;
            }

            if(child_project.length==0 || child_project.length==1){
                return projects_array;
            }

    }      
    function projectDropDownChanged(dropdown,eventArgs){

        projectName = eventArgs.value;

        //loadTeamMembersDropDown();

    }

    function loadTeamMembersDropDown(){

        var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource("__WORKSPACE_OID__","__PROJECT_OID__","__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__","__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__");
        var rallyqueryObject = {
            key: "projects",
            type: "project",
            fetch: "TeamMembers,Name",
            query: rally.sdk.util.Query('Name = "' + projectName + '"' ),
            order: "Name desc"
        };

        rallyDataSource.findAll(rallyqueryObject,processTeamMemberResult);
    }
    function processTeamMemberResult(results){

        var teamMember = results.projects;
    }
    rally.addOnLoad(onLoad);


</script>

    <style type="text/css">

        .teamApp {
        /* Add app styles here */
        }

    </style>
```

Approach 2: Approach 2 is when I activate my recursive function and it also gives me the correct array, I then use `data.push({label: all_projects[i].Name, value: all_projects[i].Name});` As seen in the code, to construct the data inside data array in the right format, and then pass it to the `sdk.ui.basic.Dropdown` constructor. But for some reason, I get no output when I run this in Rally. I do not even get dropdown box display in Rally, just a blank app.

Here is my code:

```
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>


<!--App information-->
<meta name="Name" content="App: TeamApp"/>
<meta name="Version" content="1.0"/>
<meta name="Vendor" content=""/>

<!--Include SDK-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/1.29/sdk.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    var projects_array = new Array();
    var child_project = new Array();
    function onLoad() {
        //Add app code here


        loadProjectDropdown();
    }

    function loadProjectDropdown()
    {

        var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource("__WORKSPACE_OID__","__PROJECT_OID__","__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__","__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__");


        var queryArray = new Array();
         queryArray.push({
            key:"projects",
            type:"project",
            fetch: "Children,Name",
            query: rally.sdk.util.Query('ObjectID = "' + '__PROJECT_OID__' + '"')   

            });

        rallyDataSource.findAll(queryArray,processQueryArray);

    }

    function processQueryArray(results){

        var data = new Array();

        var project = results.projects;

        /*
         * 
         * This is just a test from Rohan
         */
        var all_projects = new Array();
        //data.push({label: project[0].Name, value: project[0].Name});

        /*if(project[0].Children != null)
        {
            for(var i=0;i<project[0].Children.length;i++)
            {
                //document.write("Number "+i+" "+project[0].Children[i].Name);
                data.push({label: project[0].Children[i].Name, value: project[0].Children[i].Name});
            }
        }*/


        //pass the first parent project to a function that recursively gets all child projects.

        all_projects = get_child_recursively(project[0]);   


        //document.write(JSON.stringify(all_projects));

        for(var i=0;i<all_projects.length;i++)
        {
            data.push({label: all_projects[i].Name, value: all_projects[i].Name});
            //document.write(JSON.stringify(all_projects[i]));
            //data.push({label: all_projects[i].Name, value: all_projects[i].Name});
        }

        projectDropDown = new rally.sdk.ui.basic.Dropdown({label: "Select Project", items: data, width: 250});
        projectDropDown.display("projectDropDown",projectDropDownChanged);
    }

    //Recursive algorithm to get all child projects of a parent project
    function get_child_recursively(parent_project)
    {


            projects_array.push(parent_project);

            if(parent_project.Children.length>0)
            {
                for(var i=0;i<parent_project.Children.length;i++)
                {
                    if(child_project.indexOf(parent_project.Children[i])<=-1)
                        child_project.push(parent_project.Children[i]);
                }
                for(var i=0;i<child_project.length;i++)
                {   var temp = child_project[i];
                    child_project.splice(i,1);
                    get_child_recursively(temp);
                }
            }
            else{
                return;
            }

            if(child_project.length==0 || child_project.length==1){
                return projects_array;
            }

    }      
    function projectDropDownChanged(dropdown,eventArgs){

        projectName = eventArgs.value;

        //loadTeamMembersDropDown();

    }

    function loadTeamMembersDropDown(){

        var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource("__WORKSPACE_OID__","__PROJECT_OID__","__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__","__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__");
        var rallyqueryObject = {
            key: "projects",
            type: "project",
            fetch: "TeamMembers,Name",
            query: rally.sdk.util.Query('Name = "' + projectName + '"' ),
            order: "Name desc"
        };

        rallyDataSource.findAll(rallyqueryObject,processTeamMemberResult);
    }
    function processTeamMemberResult(results){

        var teamMember = results.projects;
    }
    rally.addOnLoad(onLoad);
</script>
        </head>
        <body class="teamApp">
    <table>
    <tr height="50px">
        <td width="300px">
            <div id="projectDropDown"></div>
        </td>                     
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>  
    </html>
```

I tried various methods for debugging by printing the `data` array in approach 1 and `data` array from approach 2 and compared the JSON format that is stored and both look similar. Still , for some reason, the `data` array from approach 1 is loaded by the dropdown box while I see nothing when I try to load `data` array from approach 2.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were duplicates in the array that was returned to me, because of duplicate project names in my workspace inside Rally. The `key` shouldn't contain duplicates when it is passed to the dropdown container.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the latest AppSDK 2rc1. Documentation for it is available [here](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/).
In the code below I built two dropdowns. First, a [project picker](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.picker.project.ProjectPicker), and then, based on the project selection, a [user combobox](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.combobox.UserComboBox) is populated. The full html code to paste to a Rally custom page is [in this repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/project-user-pickers/tree/master/deploy).

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
extend: 'Rally.app.App',
componentCls: 'app',

    launch: function() {
        var c = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            items: [
                {
                xtype: 'rallyprojectpicker',
                    listeners:{
                        change: function(combobox){
                            if (!this.down('#u')) {
                                this._onProjectSelected(combobox.getSelectedRecord());
                            }
                            else{
                                Ext.getCmp('u').destroy();
                                this._onProjectSelected(combobox.getSelectedRecord());
                            }
                        },
                        scope: this
                    }
                }
            ],
        });
        this.add(c);
    },

    _onProjectSelected:function(record){
        var project = record.data['_ref'];
        console.log('project', project);


        var u = Ext.create('Rally.ui.combobox.UserComboBox',{
            id: 'u',
            project: project,
            listeners:{
        ready: function(combobox){
                            this._onUserSelected(combobox.getRecord());
        },
        select: function(combobox){
                            this._onUserSelected(combobox.getRecord());
        },
        scope: this
    }
        });
        this.add(u);
    },

    _onUserSelected:function(record){
        var user = record.data['_ref'];
        console.log('user', user);
    }
```

});

Comment: Thanks, I think there is a small bug in this, everytime I select a new project, a new dropdown box is created for team members. Ideally there should only one dropdown for team members.

Comment: Also, do you see why my existing code won't work? I am getting the data in the `data` array and adding it while creating the dropdown container.

Comment: Thanks, I added a condition to check if the user picker already exists, and if it does it is destroyed it before being recreated. I did not look at your code closely since it is using the old AppSDK 1 and the new AppSDK 2 allows to build the pickers in under 50 lines.

Comment: Based on your answer, can I get a list of projects based on the current project that I have selected? Currently I get a list of all projects irrespective of what project I am in currently. I need to get the hierarchy list of projects based on my current project and go down the branch.

Comment: If you mean by "current project that I have selected" the project that you select from the project picker, the answer is yes, you get the hierarchy of the projects. This is not a flat list, but a true project tree. If you mean by "current project" the project you are currently in Rally, the answer is no. Regardless of the project you are in, the picker shows all workspaces and projects. See the screenshot in the README.You may accesss current project `Rally.app.Context` https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/api/Rally.app.Context and write your own project combobox from scratch.

Comment: By current project I mean the "current project" that I am currently in.